# shape mismatch: value array of shape X could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape . . . X?

Tags: python, numpy

Consider: I'm trying to generate `s` samples the von mises distribution for every element of`k`, which raises an error for `k=0` (which is my null hypothesis, so I want it as accurate as possible).  I'm trying to "fudge" it by giving a low `k` and randomizing the bias direction.

Assume

```
import numpy as np
s = 1000
k = np.arange(10)
theta = np.zeros_like(k)
shp = (10,)
```

Then the following code

```
import scipy.stats as stat    
rpt = (s,) + tuple(np.ones_like(shp))
theta = np.tile(theta, rpt)
k_zero = np.logical_not(k)
theta[:, k_zero] = np.random.rand(np.sum(k_zero), s) * 2 * np.pi - np.pi
k[k_zero] = .001
ks = np.tile(k, rpt)
```

gives the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-blah>", line 1, in <module>
    theta[:, k_zero] = np.random.rand(np.sum(k_zero), s) * np.pi - np.pi / 2

ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (1,1000) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (1,1000)
```

But  . . . those shapes are the same.  Why can't I do that?

**EDIT:** as pointed out below -

```
theta[:, k_zero] = np.random.rand(s, np.sum(k_zero)) * np.pi - np.pi / 2
```

works.  Is this just a bug in the error message?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## The error message

It appears that there is a bug in the print out that you received

- [Broadcast error on assignment prints dimensions in wrong order](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5710)
- [**setitem** shape mismatch error is incorrect](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8280)

## The code fix

The problem is because your shape in the random number assignment is wrong.
Look at the following...

```
theta[:, k_zero] = np.random.rand(np.sum(k_zero), s).reshape(s,1)
```

The way you can debug such a problem is by investigating the shapes of the assigned variable and the variable you want to assign it to.

For example what I did was

```
theta.shape
np.random.rand(np.sum(k_zero), s).shape
```

and I saw that the random number came out with transposed dimensions

Comment: Is it just a bug in the error message then?  I mean if it told me the shapes were (s,1) and (1,s) it would be a pretty easy debug.

Comment: I would agree the error message isn't intuitive in this case :)